# SocketException error with code:48 when allowing MongoDB to remote connections

Tags: mongodb, remote-access, amazon-lightsail

I have an AWS ligthsail server that is running Ubuntu. I've just installed MongoDB and it works fine on local. Now I want to open it to remote with using port 27017. I've already added the port to the `Networking` list on the AWS console and added my public IP to the config file.

**Here's my command to run mongo:**

`sudo mongod --fork --config /etc/mongod.conf`

**This is the error I've got:**

```
2020-04-07T11:40:24.424+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
2020-04-07T11:40:24.424+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
2020-04-07T11:40:24.424+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
2020-04-07T11:40:24.424+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distmod: ubuntu1804
2020-04-07T11:40:24.424+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
2020-04-07T11:40:24.424+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
2020-04-07T11:40:24.424+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: { config:     "/etc/mongod.conf", net: { bindIp: "0.0.0.0,my-remote-ip", port: 27017 }, processManagement: {     fork: true, timeZoneInfo: "/usr/share/zoneinfo" }, storage: { dbPath: "the-path-to-the-db", journal: { enabled: true } }, systemLog: { destination: "file", logAppend: true, path: "/var/log/mongodb/mongod.log" } }
2020-04-07T11:40:24.424+0000 E STORAGE  [initandlisten] Failed to set up listener:     SocketException: Cannot assign requested address
2020-04-07T11:40:24.425+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] now exiting
2020-04-07T11:40:24.425+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] shutting down with code:48
```

**And this is the config of mongod:**

```
storage:
  dbPath: the-path-to-the-db
  journal:
    enabled: true
#  engine:
#  mmapv1:
#  wiredTiger:

# where to write logging data.
systemLog:
  destination: file
  logAppend: true
  path: /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log

# network interfaces
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 0.0.0.0,<my-public-ip>


# how the process runs
processManagement:
  timeZoneInfo: /usr/share/zoneinfo
```

Also, I've checked the running processes. MongoDB is not running. I'm sure of that
I also search on SO and Google but couldn't find anything. 
Could anyone lead me to solve this problem, please? Thank you!

Comment: Also, I changed the port but still same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. I added

```
security:
  authorization: "enabled"
```

to the config file and then configured `ipteables` with below commands

```
 sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --destination-port 27017 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
 sudo iptables -A OUTPUT  -p tcp --source-port 27017 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

Apparently opening ports on AWS UI wasn't enough.